# Transport equations with constant coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

> Let $X$ be the vector field given by $X = b \cdot \nabla_x + \partial_t$ where $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is fixed. Let $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$.  Assume that $u \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n \times [0,\infty))$ and $u|_{t=0} = g \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  Then $Xu = f$ if and only if $u(x,t) = g(x-tb) + \int_0^t f(x+(s-t)b,s) \ ds$.

I have shown that if $u \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n \times [0, \infty))$ solves $Xu = f$, then
$u(x,t) = g(x-tb) + \int_0^t f(x+(s-t),s) \ ds$, where $u|_{t=0} = g
\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  What I am having some difficulty doing is showing that such a $u$ is actually a solution to the given partial differential equation $Xu = f$.

It is clear to me that $Xg = 0$.  However, I don't know exactly how to deal with the integral term with applying the operator to it.  I have tried using difference quotients to show that when the operator is applied to the integral, I obtain $f(x,t)$, but it seems to get messy.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this link to see how to deal with differentiating an integral over an evolving domain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_evolution_of_integrals.

We use this to see that 
$$\partial_t\left(\int_0^tf(x+(s-t)b,s)\,ds\right)=\int_0^t\frac{\partial f(x+(s-t)b,s)}{\partial t}\,ds+f(x,t),$$
now notice that 
$$\int_0^t\frac{\partial f(x+(s-t)b,s)}{\partial t}\,ds=-\int_0^tb\cdot\nabla_xf(x+(s-t)b,s)\,ds.$$
It is also more clear that
$$b\cdot\nabla_x\int_0^tf(x+(s-t)b,s)\,ds=\int_0^tb\cdot\nabla_xf(x+(s-t)b,s)\,ds.$$
Thus
$$(b\cdot\nabla_x+\partial_t)\left(\int_0^tf(x+(s-t)b,s)\,ds\right)=f(x,t).$$

Let's try to prove the extension of the FTOC, by the FTOC (let $F$ be the antiderivative of $f$)
$$\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(t,x)\,dx=F(t,b(t))-F(t,a(t)),$$
then
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(t,x)\,dx\right)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(F(t,b(t))-F(t,a(t))\right)$$
$$=\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(t,b(t))-\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(t,a(t))+\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(t,b(t))b'(t)-\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(t,a(t))a'(t)$$
$$=\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}\frac{\partial f(t,x)}{\partial t}+f(t,b(t))b'(t)-f(t,a(t))a'(t).$$

Comment: That was precisely what I knew the calculation to be, but I don't see exactly where the extension of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus comes from. Any good reading on that? I would really like to see a proof of that statement.

Comment: I know that the more general version (for some domain $\Omega(t)$) is at least stated in Evans PDE, but I'm not sure if the proof is given (Possibly the statement is in the appendix)

Comment: No worries, I imagine if the proof is not in Evans then a reference hopefully will be

Comment: I figured out a proof, see my edit

Comment: On question I have is regarding calling $F$ the antiderivative of $f$.  Is $F$ specifically the antiderivative of $f$ regarding derivation in terms of the $x$ term only?

Besides that, I think that was a very straightforward proof and was extremely helpful.  Thank you, again.

Comment: Yes, you're right, only the $x$ derivative :)